# Images keep extending body width beyond the viewport of the webpage

Tags: html, css

The Images change every 4 seconds to a new images.

The problem is that the images have to be the same as the width of the webpage without changing the image, so enlarging or reducing it, but what happens is that if the image has a width of 3000px, for example, body width becomes 3000px. I would prefer that if you make the screen width smaller, the photo stays the same, but without scroll bar at the bottom of your image. Without changing the photo width, it no longer looks beautiful.

Is there anyway how u can make the part of the image that is beyond the viewport of the device just invisible so on Mobile?
For example crop image at Height 1000px and width 600px and for tablet crop at height 1000px and width 1200px and at full screen computer keep the height 1000px and width 2000px for an image with height 1000px and 3000px width?

HTML

```
 <html>

<head>
<title>Portfolio</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
 maximum-scale=1" />
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="image.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="modal.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">   
</head>
<body>

<section id="pageA">

<div id="container" class="container">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/mountain.png">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/mountain2.png">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/mountain3.png">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/mountain4.png">

</div>
</section>
</body>
```

CSS

```
  body {
width: auto;
}

#container {
position:relative;
width: 100%;
}

#container img {
position:absolute;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
left:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imgFade {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
17% {
    opacity:1;
}
25% {
    opacity:0;
}
92% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}

@-moz-keyframes imgFade {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
17% {
    opacity:1;
}
25% {
    opacity:0;
}
92% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}

    @-o-keyframes imgFade {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
17% {
    opacity:1;
}
25% {
    opacity:0;
}
92% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}

@keyframes imgFade {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
17% {
    opacity:1;
}
25% {
    opacity:0;
}
92% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
 }

 #container img {
-webkit-animation-name: imgFade;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-duration: 8s;

-moz-animation-name: imgFade;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-duration: 8s;

-o-animation-name: imgFade;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-duration: 8s;

animation-name: imgFade;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 8s;
 }
 #container img:nth-of-type(1) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
-moz-animation-delay: 6s;
-o-animation-delay: 6s;
animation-delay: 6s;
 }
#container img:nth-of-type(2) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
-moz-animation-delay: 4s;
-o-animation-delay: 4s;
animation-delay: 4s;
 }
 #container img:nth-of-type(3) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2s;
-o-animation-delay: 2s;
animation-delay: 2s;
  }
 #container img:nth-of-type(4) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0s;
-o-animation-delay: 0s;
animation-delay: 0s;
```

Comment: Ok, what's the question? `Mine images keep extending the webpage even if i set the body 'width: auto;' or 'width: 100%;'` What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: the images are extending beyond mine view port i editted the post

Comment: Your HTML seems incomplete, I don't see a body tag on the code you posted. It could be great if you could add a more functional code snippet. 
I also don't get why you're using css background properties since you're dealing with `img` elements. 
I see you used position absolute on the image, keep in mind that an absolute positioned element won't know parent's width.

Comment: i put the header and the container div, body and the css for the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object-fit property defines how an element responds to the height and width of its content box.
References https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

## container img {

```
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
object-fit: cover;
left:0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to make your div "class" = "container" but you've set the ID to it instead.

Then according to the [BootStrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/), you should add the class "img-fluid" to your img to make your image fit within the parent frame, and scale responsively with it.

```
<div class="container">

<img src="images/mountain.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">

</div>
```